# setting up the port with Heroku

Tags: heroku, express, bin

I am using the express generator.  It pre-sets my port to

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
```

I have not been able to deploy to heroku.  I read the logs and keep getting

```
    Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2015-07-06T10:26:24.653626+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
```

I read through some other examples of deploying and came across this page on github. https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started/blob/master/index.js#L4

This seems very similar to what I am doing.  I assume by the error it is not reading my bin www file.

Is there a work around to this?  I am not seeing what the error solution is.

Comment: The error you're getting indicates that you probably have an async error somewhere in your code. Try running your project locally the way way you run it on Heroku -- you should see the same behavior. Your app.listen(...) call is not getting ran within the first 60 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was encountering the same error. I'm new to node and still not sure what I'm doing but I changed my Procfile from `web: node app.js` to `web: node ./bin/www`. This will invoke the www file which sets logic for controlling the port number.